# Get name in KeyValuePair for given key in Angular HTML template

Tags: angular

In my Angular component I have two objects, one is reference data and the other is my actual object.  The reference data includes KeyValuePairs.  I would like to use the name values in the KeyValuePair for one of the properties of my main object.  I can't seem to figure out how I get this value (I am inexperienced in front end app development).

Reference data:

```
{
    "colors": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Purple"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Blue"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Yellow"
        }
        ]
}
```

My object:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "colorArray": [2,3]
}
```

Using `ngFor` I want to iterate over the colorArray and return the name of the color rather than the id. So my goal would be:

Blue

Yellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over each entity and getting name would quite messy in the view, you can have custom function to do that for you.

```
getColorName = (colorId) => {
    const filteredColor = this.colorsName.colors.filter(a => a.id === colorId)
    if (filteredColor.length > 0) {
      return filteredColor[0].name;
    }
    else{
      return '';
    }
  }
```

And call it like this

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let colorId of colorsObject.colorArray">{{colorId}} color is {{getColorName(colorId)}}</li>
</ul>
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6rmpjc)

Comment: Thank you I will select your answer as these seems the most reliable and easiest to implement.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have colors as object, its pretty simple to get the color name from the id.

### html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let color of colorArray">
   {{obj.colors[color-1].name}}
</ng-container>
```

### ts

```
obj = {
    "colors": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Purple"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Blue"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Yellow"
        }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a quick solution!  Your answer was not complete though: I needed to use `{{obj.colors[color - 1].name}}` as the index starts at zero and the `id` at one.  Also needed to select the property `name` or the whole object was loaded.  I like it's an easy solution (which is OK for my implementation) but this solution does need the value of id's to be sequential.  Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: That make sense, still the same thing can be achieved in one line. This solution doen't require to the id to be sequential. It could be any order. `{{obj.colors[color-1]?.name}}`. Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pipe

In HTML

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let color of object.colorArray">
  <li *ngFor="let item of data.colors | myPipe : color">{{item.name}} </li>
</ng-container>
```

in TS

```
data = {
    'colors': [
      {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Purple'
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'Blue'
      },
      {
        'id': 3,
        'name': 'Yellow'
      }
    ]
  };

  object = {
    'id': 1,
    'colorArray': [2, 3]
  };
```

pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'myPipe'
})
export class MyPipePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], filter: number): any {
    if (!items || !filter) {
      return items;
    }
    return items.filter(item => item.id == filter);

  }

}
```

appModule you should add MyPipe Pipe in declarations array

```
 declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyPipe
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Just code's solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53663427/10340388) I made a generic function, as I expect to use this for different object types:

```
getName = (id, keyValuePair) => {
  const result = this.obj[keyValuePair].filter(a => a.id === id)
  if (result) {
    return result[0].name;
  }
  else{
    return '';
  }
}
```

Which can then be used as:

```
{{ getName(colorId, "colors") }}
```